# Google Play Store is marking a device as incompatible

Tags: android

BeyondTrust Support app is being marked as incompatible in the play store for a Zebra MC9300 running Android 8.1. The application can be installed successfully manually. We are using Microsoft Endpoint  Manager (Intune) to deploy the application and it fails due to Google Play store marking the application as incompatible.

Is there any way to find out why the app is marked as incompatible?

Comment: Did you write the app?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is caused because you have a declared a `<uses-feature>` that is not present on the device.  Please review your Manifest and any feature that is not present on the device (e.g. the MC9300 does not have a SIM card), make sure you mark it as `android:required="false"`